# Grabing value with preg_match

Tags: php, request, preg-match

How would I go about trying to grab the `$_REQUEST` KEY based on a `preg_match`.
The `$_REQUEST` value will hold a value of **15h56**

To grab the `$_REQUESTS` I'm currently using

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $k => $v) {
    $a[] = "$k=$v";
}
$ref_val = implode("&", $a);
```

So basically I'm trying to determine the $_REQUEST KEY which holds this data **15h56** since the key will be generated dynamically.

I have tried doing the following

```
if(preg_match("/[0-9]n([0-9]+)[=]?(.*)$/", $ref_val, $matches)) {
$the_key_i_need = $matches[1];
```

Comment: You almost never have to worry about the help vein "quick" on this site, there is usually a race to get you a great answer.  You can remove the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use `preg_match()` - You have the data in the `$_REQUEST` array, just use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search):

```
$key = array_search( '15h56', $_REQUEST, true);
```

If your `$_REQUEST` looked like:

```
array( 'something_unknown_here' => '15h56')
```

Then `$key` would equal `something_unknown_here` after executing `array_search()`.

**Edit:** After clarifying, it seems that the value will be unknown but will match a pattern. So, you can just iterate over `$_REQUEST` to find the key, like this:

```
$found_key = null;
foreach ($_REQUEST as $k => $v) {
    if( preg_match( '#\d+h\d+#', $v)) {
        $found_key = $k;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now `$found_key` will either be `null`, indicating that no value that matched the pattern was in `$_REQUEST`, or some value, which is the key into `$_REQUEST`. Note that this will only find the first key whose value matches the pattern.

Comment: That's the problem i don't know the value of which is being posted back in the var, i'm trying to find data based on *number*h*number* if you know what i'm trying to say ?

Comment: so you want a regex of \d\dh\d\d

Comment: Peter, how would i go about adding that to preg_match in my current code pleas e?

Comment: @Curtis - I updated my answer, please see if it helps. If it is possible to have multiple values that match the pattern and you want to capture more than one key, let me know.

Comment: @nickb just added the answer you're looking for

Comment: @nickb Thank you very much you're amazing ! i'll accept your answer in 7 minutes !

Comment: @nickb, I believe he wants exactly 2 numbers, not one or more

Comment: don't forget to click on the checkmark to mark it as answered.